# How to invoke a trigger on all rows manually in postgres

Tags: postgresql

My trigger is defined the following way:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_contract_finished_at
    AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF performed_on
    ON task
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_contract_finished_at_function();
```

I now want to evoke this trigger to set the variables which are updated by the trigger. How do I do that?

Something like

```
for each row in task
execute procedure update_contract_finished_at_function();
```

I know I can update with a standard update set statement. I also want to verifiy that my trigger works on all the data correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write a slightly modified copy of `update_contract_finished_at_function` that takes type `task` as input and returns `void`.

Then replace `NEW` in the trigger function with `$1` and call the function like this:

```
SELECT copy_func(task) FROM task;
```

If the functions are almost identical, it should be good enough to test the trigget function.

Answer (score 2):

The way to manually trigger your on update trigger once would be:

```
UPDATE task SET performed_on = performed_on
```

however depending on how complicated your logic is in there and how many rows you have in the table a separate query might be significantly faster for initializing a large number of rows.

Since you mentioned you want to test the behaviour of your trigger you can clone the table or do a table or database dump and restore the data afterwards. If this is a live system you should instead do a database dump, restore to another system, add your trigger, test it, repeat from restore until you nail it... and only after you're sure it does what you want update the live system with it.

Comment: "Postgresql will not write to disk unchanged data"  No, it certainly will.  Unless the trigger actually blocks the change.

Comment: sorry, my bad, edited the reply, I thought this was default behaviour, maybe I'm confusing databases

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a PL/pgSQL function that in a loop processes all events in chronological order and calling it:

```
create or replace function process_event_history()
  returns void
  language plpgsql
  as
$$
declare
    event record;
begin
    for event in
        select id, timestamp
        from events
        order by timestamp
    loop
        update events set timestamp = event.timestamp
        where id = event.id;
    end loop;
end;
$$;

--;;
-- Execute the above function causing the trigger to run for all events.
select process_event_history();

--;;
-- Remove the temporary processing function.
drop function process_event_history();
```